# Assertions handling giving different result in "console" and "result of running suite"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, testng

I am trying to use soft assertion here to run the test so that after assertion failed also all the script with in the test should run. I have created a Listener class to validate the result and perform test. But after execution this test should fail and which is validated and showing in Eclipse "Result of running Suite" tab but not in "Console"tab and also in report test is pass with assertion error.  Please let me know if anything wrong with in the code..

please see the attached screenshots for your reference.

--Below is the test class where assertion handling happened using try-catch.

```html
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import ErrorCollectors.ErrorCollector;


public class TestValidateTitles {
 
 
 @Test
 public void ValidteTitle(){
  try{
  System.out.println("Beginning");
  
  String actual_title = "Gmail.com";
  String expected_title = "Yahoo.com";
  
  Assert.assertEquals(expected_title, actual_title);
  }catch(Throwable t){
   
   System.out.println("Error Occurred");
   ErrorCollector.addVerificationFailure(t);
   
  }
  System.out.println("Ending");
  
 }

}
```

-- Below is the class to collect error ---

```html
package ErrorCollectors;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;

public class ErrorCollector {
 
 private static Map<ITestResult, List<Throwable>> verificationFailuresMap = new HashMap<ITestResult, List<Throwable>>();


 public static List<Throwable> getVerificationFailures() {
  List<Throwable> verificationFailures = verificationFailuresMap.get(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult());
  return verificationFailures == null ? new ArrayList<Throwable>() : verificationFailures;
 }
 
 public static void addVerificationFailure(Throwable e) {
  List<Throwable> verificationFailures = getVerificationFailures();
  verificationFailuresMap.put(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult(), verificationFailures);
  verificationFailures.add(e);
 }
 
}
```

below is the code which define the listener class to validate the failure or pass of any test.............

```html
package ErrorCollectors;

import java.util.List;

import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.internal.Utils;

public class TestListenerAdapter implements IInvokedMethodListener {

 public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult result) {
  

  
  Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);
  
  if (method.isTestMethod()) {

   List<Throwable> verificationFailures = ErrorCollector.getVerificationFailures();

   //if there are verification failures...
   if (verificationFailures.size() > 0) {
    
    //set the test to failed
    result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);

    //if there is an assertion failure add it to verificationFailures
    if (result.getThrowable() != null) {
     verificationFailures.add(result.getThrowable());
    }
    
    int size = verificationFailures.size();
    //if there's only one failure just set that
    if (size == 1) {
     result.setThrowable(verificationFailures.get(0));
    } else {
     //create a failure message with all failures and stack traces (except last failure)
     StringBuffer failureMessage = new StringBuffer("Multiple failures (").append(size).append("):\n\n");
     for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
      failureMessage.append("Failure ").append(i+1).append(" of ").append(size).append(":\n");
      Throwable t = verificationFailures.get(i);
      String fullStackTrace = Utils.stackTrace(t, false)[1];
      failureMessage.append(fullStackTrace).append("\n\n");
     }
     
     //final failure
     Throwable last = verificationFailures.get(size-1);
     failureMessage.append("Failure ").append(size).append(" of ").append(size).append(":\n");
     failureMessage.append(last.toString());
     
     //set merged throwable
     Throwable merged = new Throwable(failureMessage.toString());
     merged.setStackTrace(last.getStackTrace());
     
     result.setThrowable(merged);
    }
   }
  }
 
 }
 
 public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod arg0, ITestResult arg1) {}
 
}
```

Below is my testng.xml file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<listeners>
     <listener class-name="ErrorCollectors.TestListenerAdapter"/>
</listeners>
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.collections.java.TestValidateTitles"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what was the reason of reinventing the wheel, but TestNG already has `SoftAssert` implementation. As an alternative, you could take a look at e.g. AssertJ library, which also has `SoftAssertions`.

Your particular issue is related to the wrong way of assertion error handling.

With original `SoftAssert` you could catch `assertAll` result within `afterInvocation`, instead of putting `try / catch` blocks in tests, and then manually assign required test result in case of a failure.

Answer (score 0):

The `catch` catches the `AssertionError` being thrown by `Assert.assertEquals`. That's why the error message is printed but the test is not terminated and continues to successful ending.